# Solaris 10, pkgtrans command

Tags: package-management, solaris

What is the difference between these two commands?

`1. pkgtrans /cdrom/cdrom0/Solaris_10/Product /var/spool/pkg/stream.pkg all`

`2. pkgtrans -s /cdrom/cdrom0/Solaris_10/Product /var/spool/pkg/stream.pkg all`

The two commands make the same action.

**The second question is:**
If I have file stream format package in `/export/home/memam/` which called `SUNWipc.pkg` and I want to translate it to file system format, does this command `pkgtrans /export/home/memam/SUNWipc.pkg /var/spool/pkg` translate make this operation

Answer (score 1):

The `-s` option in your first command tells pkgtrans to translate the package into a datastream package on device2 (the target).

If the device2 argument is a directory, then a filesystem type package will be placed in the directory.  If device2 is a file, a datastream package will be created.

To translate your `SUNWipc.pkg` to a filesystem type package, assuming you wanted it placed in /var/spool/pkg/, you would need to run:

```
pkgtrans /export/home/memam/SUNWipc.pkg /var/spool/pkg/ SUNWipc
```

Comment: but the first two command make the same thing, so -s has no meaning

Comment: the first two commands are only the same if device2 is a file.